# python counting rows with missing values doesn't work

Tags: python

i do'nt know why but the code to calculate rows with missing values doesn't work.
Can somebody please hlep?
[excel file showing data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z6YX3.png)
[code in IDE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Vcco.png)

in excel, the rows that have missing values were 156 in total but i can't get this in python

using the code below

```
(kidney_df.isna().sum(axis=1) > 0).sum()


count=0
for i in kidney_df.isnull().sum(axis=1):
    if i>0:
        count=count+1

kidney_df.isna().sum().sum()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

kidney_df is a whole dataframe, do you want to count each empty cell or just the empty cells in one column? Based on the formula in your image, it seems your are interested only in column 'Z'. You can specify that by using .iloc[] (index location) or by specifying the column name (not visible in your imgage) like so:

```
kidney_df.iloc[:, 26].isnull().sum()
```

Explaination:

```
.iloc[]  # index location
:  # meaning -> from row 0 to last row or '0:-1' which can be shortened to ':'
26 # which is the column index of column 'Z' in excel
```

Comment: thanks for answer,
i try to get the number of rows that have no missing values across all the columns. What shuld i do in this case?
Currently with using the code you suggested, i have this error ->  ......... raise IndexError("single positional indexer is out-of-bounds")

Comment: @070701 if each row should count only once even if it has multiple nan values you can use this: `df.isna().apply(any, axis=1).sum()` if that doesn't work check if your excel file is maleformatted, could be that empty rows at the end are read because of a single character somewhere

Comment: Thanks a lot! how did you know that? i was struggling with it every day wasting all day

Comment: @070701 lets just say you are not the only one having wasted hours/days with that problem. ;) If the answer was helpful, please consider upvoting/accepting the answer, this will help future readers and will give me (and you) a few points. Good luck and happy coding!

Comment: Thank you! That relieves my feeling of failure.